# MySQL database search that returns multidimensional array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I have a table that looks like so:

```
user | language
-----|---------
john | english
john | french
john | spanish
```

Is there a query that I can run so that I get back:

```
["john"=>["english", "french", "spanish"]]
```

I am trying to avoid having to do something along the lines of:

```
$john->languages = array();
foreach($results as $row){
    array_push($john->languages, $row["language"]);
}
```

Comment: Mysql doesn't return 'arrays', so to speak - it returns 'rows' - which for all intents and purposes is an 'array', but there is no way to get a row that contains other rows - or a multidimensional array. You are stuck using php to create a multidimensional array out of the one-dimensional rows returned by mysql.

Comment: @MarkM, that's what I was afraid of. I was about to do this when I thought about it for a second and realized that it's horribly inefficient and hoped there was a better way.

Comment: I don't think it's all that inefficient - seems pretty standard to use Fabricator's method below. However, look at Barmar's answer - maybe there is a way after all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the conventional way

```
$user_languages = array();
foreach($result as $row) {
  $user_languages[$row['user']][] = $row['language'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use PDO, you can use its `FETCH_GROUP` option:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT user, language FROM table");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP, 0);
```

The third argument is the zero-index column number to use for the grouping. See

http://www.php.net//manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

for examples.

Comment: Nice solution. +1. Just tested - if you remove the `0` parameter ([Reference](http://www.php.net//manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#example-999)), it works perfectly. Result: `[['John'] => ['english', 'french', 'spanish']]`.